# Write selection of columns to separate CSVs by group in R

Tags: r, csv, group-by

I would like to write separate csv's from one dataframe, but the csv's should be named after a grouping variable and only contain 3 specific columns (among potentially many). Does anyone have any tips?

Here's a minimal example. What I'd like to do is write a csv for each *subject_nr* (named "101.csv", "102.csv", etc.) where the csv's only contain the columns *item*, *start_time*, and *end_time* for the relevant *subject_nr*.

```
df <- data.frame("subject_nr" = c("101", "101", "101", "102", "102", "103", "103", "103"),
             "item" = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
             "start_time" = c(50, 52, 55, 53, 54.5, 12, 15, 17),
             "end_time" = c(51, 54, 60, 53.5, 55.5, 14, 16.5, 19),
             "extra_variable"= c("s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"))
```

For example, the resulting csv ("101.csv") for the first *subject_nr* (101) should look like (with no line numbering or anything like that):

```
"item","start_time","end_time"
"a",50,51
"b",52,54
"c",55,60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst <- split(df[, c("item","start_time","end_time")], df$subject_nr)
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i){
  write.csv(lst[[i]], paste0(names(lst)[i], ".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response! When I try this, I get the error "Error in lst[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It worked well with your sample data, it should work ok if you first convert your df into a list by applying `split`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Thanks for the help!! Can you add 'row.names=FALSE' to the write.csv for future people, otherwise it adds row numbers of course. Thanks again!